# Changing css in partial view using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I've got a view with a button and below that a div that is filled using ajax and a partial view.

This is the code that belongs to the button on the view;

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-release', function () {
    StartReleaseVersionEdit();
    ReleaseVersionEdit();
}
```

Using Ajax I can alter the data that is displayed inside the table, this happens when I click the button at the top of the page;

```
function StartReleaseVersionEdit() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ChangelogMavisTabel")';
    url = url + '?order=0&paging=1000';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("div#changelog").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This code works flawlessly. Once I want to alter the css of an element inside this partial view using JQuery to set the display to none, it works for a split second but then returns to its default value right after.

```
function ReleaseVersionEdit(){    
    $('.releasebutton').css('display','inline');
    // .releasebutton default display=none
}
```

What can I do to make this work correctly? I can't put the JQuery inside the partial view's code because it is triggered by the button on the view.

Comment: Simply move the ReleaseVersionEdit function into the success method of your AJAX call

Comment: Ajax is async. Your calling the `ReleaseVersionEdit()` function before your view is loaded. Call the function in the success callback (after `$("div#changelog").html(data);`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `ReleaseVersionEdit()` function into the success method of your AJAX call, that way you can guarantee it is only called after the partial is loaded. Remember the AJAX call is asynchronous - [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-release', function () {
     StartReleaseVersionEdit();
  // ReleaseVersionEdit(); Remove from here as this could execute before the partial is loaded
}

function StartReleaseVersionEdit() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ChangelogMavisTabel")';
    url = url + '?order=0&paging=1000';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("div#changelog").html(data);
            ReleaseVersionEdit(); // Added here so will always be called after the partial has been loaded
        }
    });
}
```